# How to replace special characters with gsub in R?

Tags: r, utf-8, gsub

I have a text that is written with the old version of romanian letters.

| Old | New |
| --- | --- |
| **ş** (s with a cedilla) UTF-8: c59f | **ș** (s with a comma) UTF-8: c899 |
| **ţ** (s with a cedilla) UTF-8: c5a3 | **ț** (t with a comma) UTF-8: c89b |

When I export the text from R into a text file, this causes problems (this special letters are exported as s and t). I've manually changed some of the letters, and there where exported correctly.

How can I replace in R the old and new versions of these letters?

**So far I have tried:**

```
x<-"ş__s"
gsub("ş","ș",x) # this replaces the letter s also (output: s__s)
gsub("\xc5\x9f","\xc8\x99",x) # this does nothing
gsub("c59f","c899",x) # this does nothing
```

I hope this is explained clear enough.
Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: `gsub("ş","ș",x,fixed=TRUE)` should work,  see https://ideone.com/en3P43

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried, this does not change anything. It still changes the s into ș.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If writing the characters as-is does not work, you can try using the unicode expression.
Here is the unicode expressions of the relevant letters from Wikipedia.

```
ş  U+015F (351)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9E
ţ  U+0163 (355)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A2

ș  U+0219 (537)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-comma
ț  U+021B (539)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-comma
```

You can do the conversion in R as below.
`Utf8ToInt` is convenient to verify that the letters are converted as intended.

```r
x <- "ş__ţ"
utf8ToInt(x)
# 351  95  95 355

x2 <- gsub("\u015F", "\u0219", x)
utf8ToInt(x2)
# 537  95  95 355

x3 <- gsub("\u0163", "\u021B", x)
utf8ToInt(x3)
# 351  95  95 539
```

By the way, since this is letter-to-letter conversion, `chartr` function is more efficient than `gsub` because you can convert multiple pairs of letters at once like below.

```r
x4 <- chartr("\u015F\u0163", "\u0219\u021B", x)
utf8ToInt(x4)
# 537  95  95 539
```